Is there a way to confirm a matrix multiplication solution in O(n)
Let A, B matrices of dimensions
$\sqrt{n} * \sqrt{n}$
So that each has a total of n elements.
Let there be a matrix C.
Is there a known way to confirm wether C is the product of the two or not, in O(n)? Psuedo randomness is allowed.

Don't answer in the comments. Edit your post so that it contains all the informations.

See Freivalds’s algorithm.

@EmilJeřábek If so, I assume there's no O(n) algorithm, because if there was, Frivald's algorithm won't be a thing.

Read it again. Freivalds’s algorithm is an $O(n)$ algorithm in your notation. Everyone else uses $n$ to denote the dimension of the matrix, not the number of its entries.

Yes, Freivald's algorithm meets all of your requirements.
